# Trying to set up a Ruby Mailer and I am receiving: ActionView::MissingTemplate

Tags: ruby, email, templates, mailer

I am attempting to add a mail function to my yelp clone to notify users when a comment by another use has been left on a restaurant location they have created. When I try to force an email in my rails console, I receive this error: `ActionView::MissingTemplate`

This is for Ruby Rails 5 which has a mailer built in. I've attempted to add a Doctype template to my Mailer code and this still errors in this way.

**This is my NotificationMailer.rb:**

```
class NotificationMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "no-reply@nomsterapp.com"

  def comment_added
    mail(to: "*****@yahoo.com",
      subject: "A comment has been added to your place")
  end
end
```

**This is the ApplicationMailer.rb:**

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'from@example.com'
  layout 'mailer'
end

class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
end
```

**This is the comment_added.html.erb:**

```
<p>Hey There!</p>
<p>
   Congrats! <b>A comment has been added on Nomster</b>
</p>

Aloha,<br />
Eric
```

```
I should be able to input in the console NotificationMailer.comment_added.deliver and it send me an email. But the console kicks this error back to me:

NotificationMailer#comment_added: processed outbound mail in 574.8ms
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):6
        1: from app/mailers/notification_mailer.rb:14:in `comment_added'
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template notification_mailer/comment_added with "mailer". Searched in:)
  * "notification_mailer"
```

Comment: Is it `Comment_added.html.rb` or `comment_added.html.rb` (note the case of the first letter)?

Comment: It's lowercase, not sure why it capitalized it here.

Comment: There should be 2 template files: `app/views/notification_mailer/comment_added.html.erb` and `app/views/notification_mailer/comment_added.text.erb`. Do they exist?

Comment: yes I have the text version as well.: comment_added.text.erb

Comment: Is `app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb` there?

Comment: this is the mailer.html.erb:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
      /* Email styles need to be inline */
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is in the name of `comment_added.html.rb` it should be `comment_added.html.erb`
Also you should make sure it's under this directory app/views/notification_mailer/

Comment: I misstyped, it actually is comment_added.html.erb, however, it is not in views/notification_mailer, it's just under app/mailers

Comment: That's the issue it's finding it under app/views/notification_mailer/

Comment: So would I just need to change the folder for comment_added.html.erb and comment_added.text.erb to app/views/notification_mailer/ from apps/mailers?